# Forest Admin is not showing the model in production yet showing it in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, forestadmin

Used to Forest admin I'm not clear on how to make a model appear in the interface. Here my model "Abonnes" is showing in dev mode but while I did run heroku run rake db:migrate, it is not showing in production mode.

Anything that I might be missing ?

Best

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Layout Editor" (orange) mode available to configure your UI using drag'n'drop. You can refer to the user guide if it's not straight forward: https://docs.forestadmin.com/documentation/reference-guide/views/using-the-layout-editor-mode

Using this mode, it's pretty easy to show/hide a collection. By default, a new collection appears automatically on your development environment. However, on production, new collections are considered as hidden by default. If you want to see them, just show them on the navigation bar when your Layout Editor is enabled.

Comment: link is broken in this answer